# Clojure : event listener on domina library

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

i hope someone can help me on this.

I'm using [domina](https://github.com/levand/domina)   and clojurescript in my website project.
My problem is i try to make 3 click event in 3 different button.

I attach the code snippet below,

```
      (defn html1 []
            (dom/set-inner-html! (dom/by-id "idofhtml") "<h1> lorem ipsum </h1>"))

(defn html2 []
            (dom/set-inner-html! (dom/by-id "idofhtml") "<h1> lorem ipsum2 </h1>"))

(defn html3 []
            (dom/set-inner-html! (dom/by-id "idofhtml") "<h1> lorem ipsum3 </h1>"))

    (defn ^:export init []
        (when (and js/document
            (.-getElementById js/document))
                (ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link1") :click html1)
                (ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link2") :click html2)
                (ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link3") :click html3)))


    (set! (.-onload js/window) init)
```

Problem is only :

```
(ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link1") :click html1)
```

working, the other two :

```
 (ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link2") :click html2)
 (ev/listen! (dom/by-id "link3") :click html3)
```

Doesn't work, 
Thank you in advance, appreciate any help

Comment: you have `html2` and `html3` defined somewhere?

Comment: yes, it's pretty much same like html1,
it goes like this :
(defn html2 []
        (dom/set-inner-html! (dom/by-id "idofhtml") "<h1> lorem ipsum2 </h1>"))

Comment: Do you have html elements with the id for link2 or link3?

Comment: oh my god, shame on me to not pay attention in html file closely, i'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience, thank you @DanielCompton ....
Now how do i close this question...